# math libraries for C# (Extreme.Numerics.Professional.Net20)

Tags: c#-4.0

how I can calculate double integral?>>>
∬▒〖xy+y√x〗
their is any reference about this library for C#?
thanks for any help.....

Answer (score 0):

try math.h or cmath commands you can find [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/)